# Google.ru detects my location even behind anonymous HTTP proxy server, how?

Tags: firefox, proxy, geolocation

My steps:

1. Install brand new Windows 7 in VirtualBox
2. install Firefox
3. Select public anonymous proxy that I have never used before
4. Open Firefox, set anonymous HTTP proxy, set `geo.enabled = false` in
   `about:config`
5. Open `http://www.google.ru/`, write query

Through this way, Google still knows my real location. The only way to hide it is telling Firefox to use a SOCKS5 proxy.

**UPDATE 1**
System-wide anonymous HTTP proxy setting (via Internet Options) works the same way. Google sees my real location.

**UPDATE 1**
Problem solved. See my answer.

Comment: Where is the proxy located?

Comment: Maybe cookies... Is the problem only restricted to Firefox (that has some dealings with Google) or does the same happen in IE?

Comment: @terdon, proxy from Germany, but google shows exact part of Moscow city, where i am sitting right now :/

Comment: Most likely, the proxy isn't actually anonymyzing.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, there are no cookies - its a fresh install of a browser. Proxy server is anonymous, i am not an idiot :/. I installed opera browser and configured system-wide proxy - google also sees my location. If i configure socks proxy, it does not.

Comment: Mystical things happen, really

Comment: What do you call "System-wide anonymous http proxy setting ( internet options )"? This: http://i.imgur.com/cd9q6fo.jpg ? Firefox ignores these settings, you need to configure it here: http://i.imgur.com/IkJKjUR.png

Comment: because in soviet russia google proxys you! ... no jokes now - tracert your proxy and analise the jumps. maybe theres something there you can use.

Comment: Setting a proxy through the Internet Options panel does not make it "system-wide".

Comment: @ThatBrazilianGuy, you are wrong - firefox does not ignore proxy, that i set in "Internet options" in control panel ( latest firefox + windows7 )

Comment: @OliverSalzburg, sorry for using wrong term - setting proxy in "internet options" affects all web browsers. I meant that.

Comment: HIGHLY relevant: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/conversation/proxy-settings-on-firefox-23-for-windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real reason is very simple.

Http proxy does not support https, ha-ha.
So there were several direct requests made to google, avoiding http proxy ( but not socks proxy, of course ).

Thank you!
P.s. i used windows network monitor to analyze web browser traffic

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your HTTP proxy forwards your real ip address.
Check it on a page like this one http://www.lagado.com/proxy-test

Comment: Http proxy is anonymous, it does not forward my real ip address

Answer (score 0):

Your proxy also sends an X-FORWARDED-FOR header to the sites you browse. The X-FORWARDED-FOR contains your real IP address. You can check this [here](http://ip-check.info)

Unfortunately, there's nothing you can do from your own side; the only solution is to find a different proxy.

Comment: Http proxy is anonymous, it does not forward my real ip address

Answer (score 0):

Using a HTTP proxy is by no means a way to anonimize your data traffic. This is because DNS requests are still done directly. Maybe google uses a simple Javascript DNS request to figure this out?

Also see polipo, an HTTP proxy used by Tor, which tells you if you have been doing DNS requests behind its back (e.g. which could have been detected).